Algebraic topology of Lie group, classifying space, and homogeneous space
I'm interested in the homotopy theory (homotopy group, homology group, homotopy type, etc.) about compact Lie groups, their classifying spaces, and homogeneous spaces, as well as the interplay among them.
Also, I'd like to understand the relationship between their homotopy and their differential/combinatory geometry.
Q. Are there any monographs (books, lecture notes, etc.) on this topic?
In the past, I merely learned many scattered results/techniques from scattered sources.
So I'm looking for a more or less comprehensive reference about this.
